# Pipeline Job With Parallel Reports Both: Test Result (no failures) Show all failed tests >>>

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I run my pipeline job, I get both a **no failures** message and a **Show all failed test** message.  My win branch of the parallel had all pass and completed 2nd as windows is slower than lin.  My lin branch had one failure.

`Test Result (no failures)
Show all failed tests >>>`

How can I refactor my pipeline to ensure that tests from each branch are processes as a whole?

**Pipeline Script**

```java
@NonCPS
void emailNotification(def message) {

   emailext attachLog: true, 
   body: """<a href="${env.BUILD_URL}">"${env.JOB_NAME} ${env.BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME}</a> """, 
   replyTo: 'build@mydomain.com', 
   subject: "${env.JOB_NAME} ${env.BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME}: ${message}", 
  to: "..."
}

def problems = []
def branches = [:]

def reportProblem(def message) {
  error " ********* ${message}"
  problems.add(message)
}

@NonCPS
def addArchiveSteps(String platform) {
println "Add Arch ************ ${platform}"
  step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: "${platform}/**/build/reports/**,**/build/*.log", excludes: null])  
  step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: "${platform}/**/test-results/*.xml", fingerprint: false])
  junit "${platform}/**/test-results/*.xml"
}

def prepWorkspace(String platform) {
  println "PrepWS Arch ************ ${platform}"

  // Main Checkout
 checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], browser: [$class: 'GithubWeb', repoUrl: '....]]])

}


echo "***** Prepare Linux Branch"
branches["LinuxBuild"] = {
  node('linx64&&slave')
  {
    timestamps {
      def platform="Linx64"
      try 
      {
        ws("/opt/builds/build-dir/MyPipelineJobWorkspace")
        {

          withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=/opt/tools/Java/jdk1.7.0_79"]){

            prepWorkspace(platform)

            try {
              sh "${platform}/gradle/bin/gradle -p ${platform} clean build -x test --refresh-dependencies"
              sh "${platform}/gradle/bin/gradle -p ${platform} test"
            } catch (Exception e) {
              reportProblem("Failing ${platform} Build due to ${e.message}")
            } finally {
              sh "${platform}/gradle/bin/gradle -p ${platform} jacocoTestReport"
              addArchiveSteps(platform)
            }             
          }

        }
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
      } catch (Exception e) {
        reportProblem("Failing ${platform} Build due to ${e.message}")
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
      }
      finally 
      {
        sh "rm -r /opt/builds/build-dir/MyPipelineJobWorkspace"
      }
    }
  }
}

echo "***** Prepare Windows Branch"
branches["Windows Build"] = {
  node('winx64&&slave')
  {
    timestamps {
      def platform="Winx64"

      try 
      {
        ws("D:\\builds\\build-dir\\MyPipelineJobWorkspace")
        {

          withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=D:\\tools\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_79"]){

            prepWorkspace(platform)

            try {
              bat "${platform}\\gradle\\bin\\gradle -p ${platform} clean build -x test --refresh-dependencies"
              bat "${platform}\\gradle\\bin\\gradle -p ${platform} test"
            } catch (Exception e) {
              reportProblem("Failing ${platform} Build due to ${e.message}")
            } finally {
              bat "${platform}\\gradle\\bin\\gradle -p ${platform} jacocoTestReport"  
              addArchiveSteps(platform)
            }
          }
        }           
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
      } catch (Exception e) {
        error "Failing ${platform} Build due to ${e.getMessage()}"
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
      }
      finally
      {
        bat "rd /s/q D:\\builds\\build-dir\\MyPipelineJobWorkspace"
      }
    }
  }
}

stage name: 'Build', concurrency: 1
echo "***** Execute Branches"
parallel branches

stage name: 'Deploy', concurrency: 1
echo "***** Deploy"

if (problems.size == 0) {
  node('linx64&&slave')
  {
    timestamps {
      try 
      {
        def platform="Linx64"  
        ws('/opt/builds/build-dir/MyPipelineJobWorkspace')
        {
          echo 'Publish'

          withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=/opt/tools/Java/jdk1.7.0_79"]){
            prepWorkspace(platform)

            sh "${platform}/gradle/bin/gradle -p ${platform} clean build publish -x test --refresh-dependencies"

          }
        }
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
      } catch (Exception e) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        reportProblem("Failing Deploy because ${e.message}")
      }
      finally 
      {
        sh "rm -r /opt/builds/build-dir/MyPipelineJobWorkspace"
      }
    }
  }  
} else {
  error "${problems.size()} problems found\n-------------------\n\t"
  error problems.join("\n\t")
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I see exactly the same behavior, after I added an additional call to junit (inside a parallel step).

Comment: @jherb it is still a problem.  Too low priority to focus on for now.  I think the right solution is to archive artifacts in each OS execution and create a final stage called "report" where I gather these artifacts together and then run the junit on the.   so: 1, build/test win, archive test results -- build/test/lin, archive test result, 2. unpack lin results to results/lin, unpack win results to results/win, junit "results/**/test-results/*.xml"

Comment: @jherb, if that works for you, let me know.  In theory the individual build steps per platform should be unimportant and the final results stage is where all users should go for info about the build.  Even to download installers etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I also fixed my problem by moving the call to junit to the last stage executed after all tests have been finished. What I do not understand is, why this problem appeared now with this change: It worked with two calls to junit, but after I added a third one (actually between the existing ones), the problem described by you showed up.